# django: field error passing name through url

Tags: python, django

> FieldError: Cannot resolve 'name' into field.  Choices are: heading,
>   id, bookname.

want to pass `book.heading` as name through url. no error when i pass id but only want to pass heading not id as requirement. 
how to do it?

```
urlpatterns= [
    path('getCatBlogs/<heading>', views.                       
catblogs) 
    ]
```

Comment: Can you please post some code? Maybe your urls.py file with the patterns could be of more help.

Comment: Can you share your model, I want to know what your heading looks like. However you can add slug field in your model or slugify in your views, make it blank and open with `<str:slug>` which will give you your desired url.